# Tricky little jquery selector one : loop over all inputs, and exclude only non-checked radio buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

Here's the deal : in order to build a correct series of parameters, i'm trying to loop over all inputs included in an ajax built form;
Code down here isn't finished, yet I guess you will understand it :

```
$("#formulaireUploadFichier").live('submit',function(e){
    var fm = $(this);
    var fld = [];
    $('input',fm).not('[type=submit]').each(function(){
        if ($(this"[type=radio]:checked"||$(this).not("[type=radio]"))
        var name= $(this).attr("name");
        var val= $(this).val();
        fld.push(name+'='+val);
    });
    //construct url (note : should really be encoded!)...
    var url = fm.attr('action')+'?'+fld.join('&');
    //open shadowbox...
    Shadowbox.open({
        player:"html",
        content:url,
        width:800,
        height:800
    });
    //prevent form submission...
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The itchy part comes line 5, where i'm trying to write a correct selector for JQuery to pass over non checked/selected radio buttons.
I know i'm not that far from it, but I'm getting messed up, so any help clearing this help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already in a loop of your input elements, no need to start another. Just test for the proper filters on each item.

```
if($(this).is(":radio:checked,:not(:radio)")) {
        var name= $(this).attr("name");
        var val= $(this).val();
        fld.push(name+'='+val);
}
```

jQuery's is() function lets you compare an element to a selector that you pass as a parameter.

Comment: I've just started on jQuery like 2 days ago so I may be wrong, but I believe this selects all radio buttons that are not checked. I think the user intends to select all inputs EXCEPT radio buttons that aren't checked.

Comment: The user is already iterating over the inputs. jQuery's `is()` function lets you test an element to see if it matches a given selector. It returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Ah okay, looking at it now I get it. Select checked radio buttons and then select no radio buttons.

Comment: Yes, it will return 'true' for all that are either 'unchecked radios' or 'not radios'.

Comment: Correct, thanks for the tip. I guess I'll just have to work out selectors a bit, as syntaxt is soooo easy when you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up something near `$(this"[type`

EDIT:

```
var inps=$('input');
var whatYouWant = inps.filter('[type!=radio]').add(inps.filter('[type=radio]:checked'));
```

this way it should do what You wanted

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns a collection of radios that are not checked. That (according to his example) is what he wants.

Comment: Ok, now I see what's bad, but next time don't end Your negative comments with "This is what he wants" ;) 
I'm fixing the answer in edit

Comment: Oops. Meant to say it isn't what he wants. Thanks for the correction. Hope I wasn't too negative. Giving you a +1 for settin' me straight!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to select:

- Just checked radio buttons, or
- All checked radio buttons AND checkboxes?

Code for just checked radio buttons:

```
if($(this).is(":radio:checked")) {
```

Code for all checked inputs (checkboxes and radio buttons):

```
if($(this).is(":radio:checked, :not(:radio):checked")) {
```

I hope this is what you're after.

Answer (score -1):

What are your expected resutls here?

```
    $('input',fm).not('[type=submit]').each(function(){
    if ($(this"[type=radio]:checked"||$(this).not("[type=radio]"))
    var name= $(this).attr("name");
    var val= $(this).val();
    fld.push(name+'='+val);
     });
```

What I see here is that if it's checked or not a radio you want the conditions below to fire.  Youre missing thought the {} to surround the code, all youre doing is setting the var name when you meet the condition.  Do you mean to have it run all that code? like this?

```
    $('input',fm).not('[type=submit]').each(function(){
if ($(this"[type=radio]:checked"||$(this).not("[type=radio]")){
var name= $(this).attr("name");
var val= $(this).val();
fld.push(name+'='+val);
}

 });
```

Comment: Interesting this was downflaged yet the code clearly wont set that name variable based on what the original poster posted.

Comment: Toward whom is that directed? You commented your own answer.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest to replace `if ($(this"[type=radio]:checked"||$(this).not("[type=radio]"))` by `if($(this).attr('type') !== 'radio' || $(this).val()=='on')`